# CRM 2011: ReportViewer iframe height=100% not rendering in Internet Explorer

Tags: iframe, height, dynamics-crm-2011, reportviewer, percentage

In my CRM 2011, I have a dashboard that contains a report. This report opens correctly on any browser  but Internet Explorer.

I did some trials and it turns out to be a problem with the IFrame height of the reportviewer which is set to "100%" it's not rendered correctly, however when the height is set to a fixed value it works fine.

Firefox has a fix, it adds a dummy "div" with height=100% as a container for the reportviewer with the following CSS:

```
IE7-Height-Fix-Dummy-Container {
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%
}
```

When I remove the check from "Height: 100%", Firefox does the same behaviour with IE, the IFrame shrinks to just a few lines clipping the report content.

The solutions I found online was to change the css of the reportviewer or the page itself, but I'm unable to do that with a System Dashboard, it's not a webresource I can adjust manually. Has anybody got a solution for this ?

Comment: You can set the iframe height and width from the form Properties.

Comment: It's not a web resource? How did you put a report in a dashboard ?

Comment: Using this method: http://srmscrm.wordpress.com/2013/04/15/370/

Answer (score 0):

Ok Customize you iframe to your required height:

Settings->Customization->Customize the system->Entity(i.e Account)->Form->

Select Your IFrame

Change Properties->

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I went to "Customizations" --> "Dashboards" --> Clicked on my IFrame and "Edit Components", I found no tabs in this window, only one main tab in which you put the URL